# While loop adding two numbers

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to write a very basic code.
Add two numbers,next add another number given by user,print result,ask for another,add to previous result,print new result.

I've started with that:

```
a=int(raw_input('give a number'))
b=int(raw_input('give second number'))
y=True
n=False
while input('Continue? (y/n)') != 'n':
   c = a + b
   print c
   b = int(raw_input('give another number'))
```

Ok I've correct code by your tips.I am appreciate but it stil doesn't work.It add two numbers,print result then ask for another add to result(right now its ok) But when you enter another it add to a and then print.
Maybe you see what is wrong?

And when I enter "n" it didn't end the program

Comment: Well tell us in words what you want to be the stopping condition.  A non-integer (e.g. the letter 'x')?  No input at all (user just hits enter)?

Comment: `while input('Continue? (y/n)') != 'n':`

Comment: And if `print d` prints what you expect it to print, it looks like you're using Python 2.x and should look into [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

Comment: It should ask user if he want to stop and then enter "end" should end program

Comment: @wiedzminYo Then you can just ask for user input like this: `while input('please enter "end" to exit')`, which is something similar to @C.B. 's comment above

Comment: @C.B. How I should define "y" "enter",as a boolen  or int?

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid using `input()` in lieu of `raw_input()` (safer, and `input()` was removed in Python 3). With it, you can then turn the input into a number yourself by wrapping it with `int()` or `float()`. Then you have a couple possibilities:

Loop forever, and end the loop if you get an error in conversion:

```
...
while True:
    try:
        b = int(raw_input('give another number ("x" to exit)'))
    except ValueError:
        break
    ...
```

Or, break if you see some sentinel value, for instance 0 (which conveniently evaluates as false).

```
a = 1
b = 2
while b:
    a = a + b
    print a
    b = int(raw_input('give another number'))
```

Comment: Thanks for advice about raw_input. But there is a problem, after I've tried your your way it isn't adding sum a+b just print ab like a=3 b=2 print c=32
I don't understand why

Comment: @wiedzminYo `raw_input` gets strings. You need to convert them into a number with `int` or `float`.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages, including Python, conditions must evaluate to true or false. In this case, the string `"condition"` will always evaluate to true, because only empty strings evaluate to false. In order to leave the `while` loop, you must first determine what condition is necessary to discontinue looping. With

```
while condition: pass
```

`condition` can be an `if` statement, or an object reducible to `True` or `False`. Most objects, such as lists, tuples, and strings, evaluate to `True` when not empty, and `False` when empty. The other common condition is a comparison between two values; such as

```
1 < 2
```

or

```
a is b
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest condition you could check for is EOF (end of file).  That would be when the user does not type a number but instead just types a carriage return.

It is up to you to tell the user how to end the program.  So you also have to write an instruction to them e.g.

```
b=input('give another number or type <enter> to end')
```

I'm a beginner too.  I know this solution is simplistic, but it works.

```
a=int(raw_input('Give a number'))

while True:
    print a
    userIn = (raw_input('Give another number or <cr> to end)'))
    if not userIn:
       break
    b = int(userIn)
    a = a + b
```